# Laravel: Call to a member function error() on a non-object in Exceptions/Handler.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel framework. I downloaded sample project from github. when I try to use it in my localhost it shows

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '.../vendor/autoload.php on Line 14'
```

so I update composer by `composer update`. Now new error is coming up when I execute `php public/index.php`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function error() on a non-object in /htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 47
```

Comment: It'd be a great help if you provided a link to the sample project you downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

After you downloaded a blank Laravel project you have to run `composer install` before you start your work. It will install all dependences and this error should be gone.